# How do I layout two EditTexts side by side to each other in a GridLayout?

Tags: xml, android-layout, android-edittext, layout-gravity

I have two EditTexts.  I'd like each to take up half of the UI screen width.

Below is my xml layout file.  Only the leftmost EditText ("Due Date") is showing so I'm clearing missing something here.  The rightmost EditText that should be showing is the "Due Time".  Please advise.

```
....
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/DueDate_text_input_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_row="4"
    android:layout_column="0">

<com.example.jdw.thirdscreen.ListenerEditText
    android:id="@+id/FEditText"
    android:hint="Due Date"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:inputType="text|textCapSentences|textNoSuggestions"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:maxLength="51"
    android:imeOptions="actionNext|flagNoExtractUi"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:nextFocusRight="@+id/DueTime_text_input_layout" >

</com.example.jdw.thirdscreen.ListenerEditText>
</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/DueTime_text_input_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_row="4"
    android:layout_column="1">

<com.example.jdw.thirdscreen.ListenerEditText
    android:id="@+id/GEditText"
    android:hint="Due Time"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:inputType="text|textCapSentences|textNoSuggestions"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:maxLength="51"
    android:imeOptions="actionNext|flagNoExtractUi"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:nextFocusDown="@+id/saveButton" >

</com.example.jdw.thirdscreen.ListenerEditText>
</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
...
```

Answer (score 0):

use `weight` property, available since API 21

```
<GridLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:rowCount="4"
    android:columnCount="2">

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/editText2"
        android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1" />
</GridLayout>
```